# Which way is the best to select the default selected one in a selectlist ? (dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I want to know the best way to select the default selected option which is always 0 in my case.

```
jQuery('#selectList').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

or

```
jQuery('#selectList option').prop('selected', function (){
   return this.defaultSelected;
});
```

Is it just two ways of doing the same thing or is there pros and cons?

Comment: [Better to ask on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: reset means you want to set default ??? then first one looks simple and clean

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "reset".  If you *edit* a record, the initial value will not be index=0, so resetting should not set it to 0.

Comment: I understand. No matter how many options are loaded dynamically, option 0 will always be an information text.

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 Solution

pro: it is short and likely faster

con: it sets the index to zero, maybe you set a "selected" attribute on an option with an index more than zero.
But in this case, it is always zero, so no problem.

## 2 Solution

pro: it really checks which option was first marked as selected, independently of all user changes.

con: it is a little bit long but maybe you can use arrow functions or something like that to shorten it. Also be careful cause if you don't set any selected attribute no option will return true.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!